# Is there any way to know in Spring what bean to use while being from the parent class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have this specific problem in which I can't use a `@Qualifier` cause I need the bean in the parent class. My idea is to remove the `baseComponent` propertie and make an abstract method in `BaseController` like `getComponent()` and return the desired bean for `BaseComponent` ... but perhaps there is a cleaner way to do this through configuration.

```
@RestController
public abstract class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private BaseComponent baseComponent;

    @GetMapping("/something")
    public void doSomething() {
        baseComponent.printSomething();
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class FooController extends BaseController {

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar")
public class BarController extends BaseController {

}

public interface BaseComponent {
    void printSomething();
}

@Component
public class FooComponent implements BaseComponent {

    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("foo!");
    }

}

@Component
public class BarComponent implements BaseComponent{

    @Override
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("bar!");
    }

}
```

Comment: What error or issue are you having?

Comment: The application simply won't know which bean to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the reasons I don't like autowiring directly to a private field. I would do this by injecting BaseComponent through the constructor of BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController {

   private final BaseComponent baseComponent;

   protected BaseController(BaseComponent baseComponent){
       this.baseComponent = baseComponent;
   }

   @GetMapping("/something")
   public ResponseEntity<String> getSomething(){
       return new ResponseEntity<String>(baseComponent.getSomething(), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController extends BaseController{

   @Autowired
   public FooController(@Qualifier("fooComponent") BaseComponent baseComponent) {
      super(baseComponent);
   }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bar")
public class BarController extends BaseController{

   @Autowired
   public BarController(@Qualifier("barComponent") BaseComponent baseComponent){
       super(baseComponent);
   }
}

@Component
public class BarComponent implements BaseComponent {

   @Override
   public String getSomething() {
       return "bar";
   }
}

@Component
public class FooComponent implements BaseComponent {

   @Override
   public String getSomething() {
     return "foo";
   }
}
```

Requests to /something/bar will return bar and requests to something/foo will return foo.

Note that the abstract `BaseComponent` is not actually declared as any kind of Spring component nor does it have any dependencies automatically injected. Instead, the subclasses are the components and the dependencies are wired into their constructors and passed through `super` to `BaseComponent`. The subclass constructors provide a place for the `@Qualifier` annotation to specify which `BaseComponent` you want.

In theory, I don't like declaring two classes that are identical other than the annotations. In practice, though, I have found that sometimes it is simplest just to declare classes to hold the Spring annotations. That's better than the old days of XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

@RestController
public abstract class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @GetMapping("/something")
    public void doSomething() {
        BaseComponent baseComponent = beanFactory.getBean("Foo", // or "Bar"
                                                          BaseComponent.class); 
        baseComponent.printSomething();
    }

}


@Component("Foo")
public class FooComponent implements BaseComponent {
...

}


@Component("Bar")
public class BarComponent implements BaseComponent{
...

}
```

If I right understand what you want.

Comment: That would not solve the problem, the parent class should know dynamically which bean to use and you're hardcoding the name.

Comment: This example just show how you can obtain bean dynamically by name. Based on what condition you are going to obtain bean?

Comment: If I wanted to do that I could use @Qualifier as I said. I want to know if there is any way in Spring to obtain a bean dynamically based on configuration. If not... I will go with the solution of returning the desired bean from the child classes with an overrided method.

Comment: @Qualifier can help you to specify bean at compile time, in contrast to BeanFactory that can help to specify injected bean at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics if you don't want to hardcode the bean name:

```
@RestController
public abstract class BaseController<T extends BaseComponent> {

   @Autowired
   private T baseComponent;

   ...
```

}

```
@RestController
public class FooController extends BaseController<FooComponent> {
 ...
}
```